# Limit a number of digits in expression

Tags: php, regex

Could you please help me write a regexp to limit humber of digits to 10 in a string (a telephone number). The problem is that we allow hyphens ("-") and spaces between the digit groups, so I can't just go with `/^\d{10}$/`.

So the number could be 1234 123 123, or 123-123-1234 or 1234234123, with only limitation of 10 digits.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a regular expression alone, use `preg_replace()` to strip out non-digit characters (`[^\d]`) and verify that the resultant string (digits only) length is ten:

```
if (strlen(preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $number)) !== 10) {
   // invalid
}
```

Comment: Same train of thought, but you worded it better I guess. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of your regex with [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to make sure that you got the right data from the string:

```
<?php
$str = 'abcdef';
echo strlen($str); // 6

$str = ' ab cd ';
echo strlen($str); // 7
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without using regex:

```
<?php
  $v = "123-123-1234";
  $items = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($v); $i++) {
     if ($v[$i] <= '9' && $v[$i] >= '0') {
       $items[] = $v[$i];
       if (count($items) == 10)
         break;
     }
  } 
  print_r($items);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$phone="92-456-asd-445";
$digits = preg_replace("[^0-9]", "",$phone); //92456445

if (strlen($digits)>10){
    echo "Bye";
}
else{
    echo "Hi";
}
```

Comment: `ereg_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

"So the number could be 1234 123 123, or 123-123-1234 or 1234234123, with only limitation of 10 digits."

In this example "44" part is breaking limitation;

```
$i = 0;
$s = "1234 567 890-44";
preg_match_all("/(\d+|-+| +)/", $s, $ms);
foreach ($ms[0] as $m) {
    if (is_numeric($m)) {
        $i += strlen($m);
    }
}

echo $i ."\n";
if ($i > 10) {
    echo "limit exceed!";
}
```